# Align scrollable paper-tabs in center?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there any way I can align `paper-tabs` in the center of a div? If so, how?

Custom element:

```
<div class="navigation" id="tabs">
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" scrollable noink>
        <paper-tab>fruits</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>vegetables</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>dairy</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

paper-tabs {
  height: 80px;
}

paper-tabs paper-tab .tab-content {
  color: white;
  font-family: swimfeedsraleway;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

paper-tab:not(.iron-selected) > .tab-content.paper-tab {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.paper-tabs-0 #selectionBar.paper-tabs {
  background-color: white;
}

#selectionBar.paper-tabs {
  height: 3px;
}

paper-tabs paper-icon-button {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly add either screenshots of what you're seeing now and what you're trying to achieve, or a jsfiddle containing the code above?

Comment: Also, some things to try: giving `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` to the paper-tabs element OR giving `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to the navigation class. But without more details, I can't give a thoroughly, well explained answer.

Comment: You might user Polymer styles like this: `<div class="layout horizontal center-justified">` to align everything inside the `div` to the center. The you will need to provide a width to `paper-tabs` element.